# Reviews do not show up if improve was selected in /review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

If I review an edit, and select improve, that edit does not show up in the review summary on my profile page, or on my stats for recent edits approved/rejected.

Comment: Yup, sorry, mentioned it in the title, but not in the question. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

This is by-design ... improved edits are either approved or rejected by the community user. This allows us to easily audit when this options is picked.

The actual edit performed is still attributed to you, so it is traceable and counts towards badges you get.

Comment: To be honest, it is not so much about the badges (I already have the gold editor and reviewer badges) just about looking for an edit that I remembered improving or something. It would be much easier to find if it was in the revisions tab.